# Django Official Tutorial Poll: How do you manage Choice in Admin Panel?

Tags: python, django, database, django-admin

The official tutorial (Part 2) makes it easy to add and delete Questions in the admin panel by adding admin.site.register(Question) into admin.py.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/

However I am curious how to manage the answers, the Choice object, too.
naturally I import and add admin.site.register(Choice)  into admin.py.

So it works. But I have these concerns:

A. Questions and Choice are managed separately.

B. In the Choice index menu, it doesnt show which Question (Key) a Choice is assigned to, not unless you click into each of the records to show a drop down menu of Keys you can choose from.

I would like to know how:

A. to manage Question and Choice in a more hierarchal structure, i.e. you click into a Question item and you can edit not only the Question itself but also the Choices it is affiliated with.

B. In the Choice index table menu, is it possible to list another column to show the Key object(Question) to the item?

Or if there are any other more intuitive way to do admin management?

The official Django tutorial in my opinion isn't really well explained, it took me quite sometime to google around to figure out what is really happening. It will be great too if someone here could offer a better up-to-dated tutorial for beginners like me to go and have a try.

Comment: Have you come across TabularInline fields in the docs before? Sounds like that's what you're looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: Have you already completed part 7 of the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

For admin interface your admin.py need to be:
in the `polls/admin.py`:

```
from .models import Question,Choice
admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Now you have full control over questions and answers as admin